# Android: Base64 Sample issue

Tags: android, image, base64, android-sdcard

currently I'm using kSoap to publish data to C# web services. Now I've come to the part where I need to upload images from my machine using Base64Binary. I searched everywehre internet but couldn't come up with a proper solution.

there is a solution with [external Base64 class](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html) example but I'm interested in native solution as [there is a API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) from Android 2.2.

Since I'm a newbie I couldn't do it myself. Basically I have a sd card file path of images, I want to convert them into Base64 format to upload.

Hope someone can help me or direct me to proper documents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue

```
String Image64 = null;


        try {
            Image64 = Base64.encodeToString((getBytesFromFile(new File(path))), DEFAULT);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

//encording
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, use Base64.java from link you have specified.

```
Bitmap bmImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +  "Your filename");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bmImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);   
String encodedString = Base64.encodeBytes( baos.toByteArray() );
```

You should change extension of this `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` statement according to your file type. You can decode a base 64 string to image using following code

```
byte[] b;
b = Base64.decode("base 64 string");
final Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length );
```

Comment: I have not tried it sorry. as I said I wanted the native solution.